# MSC Nastran - BAR3/4 elements - can't assign any properties

Tags: beam, buckling, nastran

I'm modeling a pipe in Patran, and I'd like to try bar3 and bar4 elements. 
I assing the properties CBEAM to my geometry, but when I create the mesh, Patran tell me bar3 and bar4 don't support that property, and I need to use bar2. 
Doesn't work even with CBAR, CROD or CPIPE. How can I use bar3 then? Seems like no properties work.

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: AFAIK Nastran doesn't have any curved beam elements with 3 or 4 nodes. Patran can generate input for other FE programs that do have such elements.

Comment: It’s just a straight beam with a circle section

Answer (score 0):

It's been forever since I've used patran, but in Nastran what you are looking for is CBEAM3. that's a 3 noded beam. CBEAM is strictly 2 nodes.